# In Python, matching the first occurrence of a word AFTER the occurrence of another word

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to replace the occurrence of a word that occurs only after another word in a JSON text string.  I have been struggling to use regular expressions to do this but using just Python functions will be fine with me.

So what I want is to find the first occurrence of `"LEVEL1"`: (with quotes), then find first occurrence of `"session_transition":`, then find whatever string is in quotes after `"session_transition":`, and then replace it with another string.  Here is the string I am working with:

```
"BASELINE": {
    "audio_volume": 150,
    "cry_threshold": 70,
    "cry_transition": "LEVEL1",
    "expected_volume": 63,
    "led_color": "BLUE",
    "led_blink_speed": "NONE",
    "motor_amplitude": 0.97,
    "motor_frequency": 0.5,
    "power_transition": "SUSPENDED",
    "seconds_to_ignore_cry": 10.0,
    "seconds_in_state": -1.0,
    "session_transition": "ONLINE",
    "track": "RoR",
    "timer_transition": null,
    "active_session" : 1
},
"LEVEL1": {
    "audio_volume": 300,
    "cry_threshold": 75,
    "expected_volume": 63,
    "cry_transition": "LEVEL2",
    "led_color": "PURPLE",
    "led_blink_speed": "NONE",
    "motor_amplitude": 0.76,
    "motor_frequency": 1.20,
    "power_transition": "SUSPENDED",
    "seconds_to_ignore_cry": 10.0,
    "seconds_in_state": 480.0,
    "session_transition": "ONLINE",
    "track": "RoR",
    "timer_transition": "BASELINE",
    "active_session" : 1
}
```

}

For instance, below I want to find and replace `"ONLINE"` under `"LEVEL1":` --> `"session_transition":` to `"OFFLINE"` so it'll look like this:

```
"LEVEL1": {
    "audio_volume": 300,
    "cry_threshold": 75,
    "expected_volume": 63,
    "cry_transition": "LEVEL2",
    "led_color": "PURPLE",
    "led_blink_speed": "NONE",
    "motor_amplitude": 0.76,
    "motor_frequency": 1.20,
    "power_transition": "SUSPENDED",
    "seconds_to_ignore_cry": 10.0,
    "seconds_in_state": 480.0,
    "session_transition": "OFFLINE",
    "track": "RoR",
    "timer_transition": "BASELINE",
    "active_session" : 1
}
```

So far I have `r"(?<=\"LEVEL1\"\:).*` to match the first occurrence but don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with regex? Parse it and process the dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I need the string to remain a string and not become a dict, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Why? Why can't you turn it back into a string afterwards? What's the *actual problem* you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was able to solve this in the following way:

```
#1)Find the unique string "LEVEL1": and save its index
after_index = configuration_in_text_format.index('"LEVEL1":')
#2)Starting from previous index, find the "session_transition": string and save its index
after_index = configuration_in_text_format.find('"session_transition":', after_index)
#3)Create a new string of bottom part with "session_transition": as first line
new_config_in_text_format = configuration_in_text_format[after_index:]
#4)Remove the first line with "session_transition": in it
new_config_in_text_format = new_config_in_text_format[new_config_in_text_format.find('\n')+1:]
#5)Create a new string to replace the deleted new line
new_line_str = '"session_transition": "OFFLINE",\n'
#6)Put new string on top of remaining text, effectively replacing old line
new_config_in_text_format = new_line_str + new_config_in_text_format
#7)Take the top part of original text and append the newly modified bottom part
new_config_in_text_format = configuration_in_text_format[:after_index] + new_config_in_text_format
print new_config_in_text_format
```

And the proper output:

```
  "BASELINE": {
    "audio_volume": 150,
    "cry_threshold": 70,
    "cry_transition": "LEVEL1",
    "expected_volume": 63,
    "led_color": "BLUE",
    "led_blink_speed": "NONE",
    "motor_amplitude": 0.97,
    "motor_frequency": 0.5,
    "power_transition": "SUSPENDED",
    "seconds_to_ignore_cry": 10.0,
    "seconds_in_state": -1.0,
    "session_transition": "ONLINE",
    "track": "RoR",
    "timer_transition": null,
    "active_session" : 1
},
"LEVEL1": {
    "audio_volume": 300,
    "cry_threshold": 75,
    "expected_volume": 63,
    "cry_transition": "LEVEL2",
    "led_color": "PURPLE",
    "led_blink_speed": "NONE",
    "motor_amplitude": 0.76,
    "motor_frequency": 1.20,
    "power_transition": "SUSPENDED",
    "seconds_to_ignore_cry": 10.0,
    "seconds_in_state": 480.0,
    "session_transition": "OFFLINE",
    "track": "RoR",
    "timer_transition": "BASELINE",
    "active_session" : 1
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this somewhat easily using string.index()

```
first_index = some_string.index('"Level1"')
second_index = some_string[first_index:].index('"Online"')
```

after that I leave it up to you to replace the string.  You should be able to do it using `some_string[second_index:].split('"')` and then use splicing and join to put it back together.

Comment: "ONLINE" that I want to replace is not the first one that I encounter; in fact, it can be any other string as long as it is in the LEVEL1-->session_transition branch.  That's why I am trying to match with "LEVEL1": first and then match with "session_transition": next (in that order).

Comment: ok, so switch the words around?  the point is the first line you match the word you want to match first, the second line you match the word you want to match second.

Comment: Thank, this led me to the solution.  I mistakenly went down the bottomless abyss of regex; lesson learned.

Comment: Sure thing!  I would appreciate an upvote or accepting my solution (accepting is best) if you truly found it helpful!  Regex is useful, but for simple things you can usually just use the built in string libraries.  Thanks

Comment: Note that `str.index` can take a `start` position to search from, you don't need to slice the string like that to get the `second_index`.

Comment: @bravosierra99 I upvoted but it doesn't show since I am a n00b here and need more reputation.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the JSON library which is inbuilt in Python. You can easily convert the JSON to a Python Dict Object. This would prevent you from complex regex as well. It's better to reduce complexity in readability as well.
**Documentation:**
[Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html)
[Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

In Python 2

```
import json
jsonDict = json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
print(jsonDict)
```

Result:

```
['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

You can then easily do manipulations as you would do to a Python Dictionary. Seems more intuitive this way.

Once you are done you can convert it using

```
jsonStr = json.dumps(jsonDict)
print(jsonStr)
```

Result:

```
["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]
```

Comment: This is a good solution and it works.  However, when I convert back to string from JSON, the data is reordered.  I know this is expected but I don't want the string modified to be out of order from its initial state.